# Regular Expressions and substring in R

Tags: r, regex, substring

I'm trying to clean and change the data into a specific format.

All data should have the following format: 2 digits, 3 letters (MKT), 4 digits, 1 underscore and 1 digit (for example 66MKT1234_1)

Let's assume that I have the following data:

```
V <- c("66MKT030_2", "66MGT1220_2", "66MGT063_1", "66MKT350_2","22233366698","66MKT3500_2", "9999999")
```

What to correct:
a) The 1st, 3rd and 4th element of the vector only have 3 digits after the 3 letters (MTG). In this case, I will need to add one 0 digit after the last letters
b) The 2nd and 3rd element need to be correct from "MGT" to "MTG"
c) the 5th and 7th element need to be removed.

My approach was to:

step 1 - remove the data that do not match the format (2 digits, 3 letters (MKT), 4 digits, 1 underscore and 1 digit)

```
aa <- grepl("\\d{2}\\w{3}\\d{3,4}[:punct:]\\d{1}", V)
V2 <- V[aa]
```

step 2  - use gsub to correct "MGT" to "MTG"

step 3 - find a way to add digit 0 after the letters if digits lenght is 3 (for example, the first element should be changed from 66MKT030_2 to 66MKT0030_2)

I am stuck in step 1, as my code does not work to clean the 5th ("22233366698") and 7th ("9999999") elements from the vector.

Can you please help me on how to do this in a cleaver way?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you might have a pretty big cleanup.  You may want to focus your question on only one of the steps you described.

Comment: Try `sub("^(\\d{2}[[:alpha:]]{3})(\\d{3}\\D)", "\\10\\2", sub("MGT", "MTG", grep("^\\d+$", V, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE), fixed=TRUE))
`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. It seems to work. Can you please explain what does the "\\10\\2" & grep("^\\d+$", V, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sub("^(\\d{2}[[:alpha:]]{3})(\\d{3}\\D)", "\\10\\2", sub("MGT", "MTG", grep("^\\d+$", V, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE), fixed=TRUE))
```

In separate steps:

```
V <- grep("^\\d+$", V, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
V <- sub("MGT", "MTG", V, fixed=TRUE)
sub("^(\\d{2}[[:alpha:]]{3})(\\d{3}\\D)", "\\10\\2", V)
```

Output:

```
[1] "66MKT0030_2" "66MTG1220_2" "66MTG0063_1" "66MKT0350_2" "66MKT3500_2"
```

**Details**

- `grep("^\\d+$", V, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)` - filters out all items that only consist of digits (`invert=TRUE` reverses the result of the `^\d+$` regex)
- `sub("MGT", "MTG", V, fixed=TRUE)` - replaces `MGT` with `MTG` (`fixed=TRUE` makes this replacement on literal strings with no regex engine involved, which usually speeds up the process)
- `sub("^(\\d{2}[[:alpha:]]{3})(\\d{3}\\D)", "\\10\\2", V)` - adds a `0` before the 3rd field that consists of three digits only.

The third step regex details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{2}[[:alpha:]]{3})` - Group 1: two digits (`\d{2}`), three letters (`[[:alpha:]]{3}`)
- `(\d{3}\D)` - Group 2: three digits (`\d{3}`) and a non-digit (`\D`)
- `\10\2` - Group 1, `0`, Group 2 value.

Comment: Just a quick question. Is there any way to return which elements from a vector (i.e. index/position of the element) were included/excluded from the original vector for this step (V <- grep("^\\d+$", V, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE))? I can not find this option in the help document for the grep function.

Comment: It seems that it needs to be done with grepl function.

Comment: @AnaAntunes `grep("^\\d+$", V, invert=TRUE)` shows `1 2 3 4 6` and `grep("^\\d+$", V)` shows `5 7`. The `value=TRUE` returns the actual character vectors, if you remove the argument, you will get the IDs. `grepl` returns boolean results and does not support `invert` argument, but if you are interested, you may play with `grepl("^\\d+$", V)` and `grepl("^(?!\\d+$)", V, perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the help. Now I understand the grep much better